# Monitor HTTP requests made by IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools, http-monitor

I thought developer tools could do this but I'm struggling to find it. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Is http://www.wireshark.org/ what you're looking for?

Comment: Wireshark is a little too "in-deep" for my requirements. Fiddler looks good though.

Comment: IE9 developer tools do it, not 8.  Use fiddler (http) or wireshark (tcp/ip).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examine http response headers in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791642/examine-http-response-headers-in-ie8)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can do it.

Answer (score 6):

[Fiddler](http://://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the best tool.
Depending on needs you can use network sniffer as well, like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or Microsoft Network Monitor.

Answer (score 5):

I have had success with [HTTP Watch Basic](http://www.httpwatch.com/).  I have tried Fiddler and wireshark.  They are great tools, assuming you have the permission to use them in a corporate environment.  Typically, the corporate security team will not allow them to be installed (at least in my situation).  I have had success with HTTP Watch Basic when debugging SAML issues for single-sign-on.  HTTP Watch basic seems to be the the primary option to use for IE8.