# How can I use IE8 Developer Tools to inspect network traffic?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, network-traffic

How can I use IE8 Developer Tools to inspect network traffic?

## Specifics:

I need to test if files have loaded or if they have loaded slow. In Firefox/Firebug I can do this by using the `NET` tab.

## Restrictions:

I cannot install additional software, so answers in [Examine http response headers in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791642/examine-http-response-headers-in-ie8) are of no use to me. :( I am debugging issues on restricted computer systems and do not have admin rights.

## Rumors?

I have read that there is no way, at all, to inspect network traffic using IE8 Developer Tools, is this true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/22/ie9-developer-tools-network-tab.aspx it says:

> The developer tools include some new capabilities and improvements
>   over the tools in IE8:
>
> ```
> A new tab for inspecting network traffic.
> ```

So this is impossible in IE8 (without installing additional software, that is).

That's that.